# Python sqlite3 - connection.commit() does not commit to database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3-python

I am writing a webserver using Flask with python.
For my backend I am using the sqlite3 python module.

My issue is that I have a query (shown bellow) which should add a new entry into the 'Sessions' table in my database, however on calling `connection.commit()` and attempting to retrieve my data, there is nothing in the table. Does anybody know what could be causing this and how I could fix it? Thank you!

```
  def Session(Date, UserId):
    print(Date, UserId)
    id = Identifiers()
    cursor.execute(("INSERT INTO Sessions VALUES ({2}, '{1}', {0})").format(UserId, Date, id.current('Session')))
    id.new('Session')
    connection.commit()
    statistics.New('DATABASE', 'writes')
    return int(id.current('Session')) - 1
```

*My function runs successfully when called, and produces no exceptions. It also returns the expected SessionId.

Comment: You seem to be executing the query _before_ opening a session.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't think to add that to my question! I open a session at the beginning of my file with ```connection = sq.connect("./Data.db", check_same_thread=False)
cursor = connection.cursor()``` Silly me!

Comment: There are a couple of problems here. First, we can't see that the cursor is associated with that connection and secondly, this is completely open to SQL Injection because you're using `format`.

Comment: It's not open to SQL injection, all parameters are passed through a filter before the functions are called. But that isn't what I was asking. The cursor is associated with the connection (see above comment)

Comment: But it's just a webserver for me to use anyway so SQL injections were never a big concern

Comment: This isn't the only query being executed, it's just this is the only one that doesn't work. All of the other queries can access the db both for read and write operations and they all use the same connection!

Comment: Liable to SQL Injection or not, you should just write your queries the correct way as it's actually easier in every case and is also more efficient. That aside, it's impossible to help you here without a [mcve]